# How to configure dual 802.11p radio in Veins 4.7.1

Tags: omnet++, veins

Does Veins support dual radio configuration? And if it does, how should I configure it? I'm working on OMNET++ 5.3, Veins 4.7.1 and SUMO 0.32.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this:

- if you want to use the simulation modules modeling an IEEE 1609 stack that come with Veins, you can simply instantiate two network interface card modules per host module, but you will need to write an application layer that takes care of implementing the logic to decide which frame gets sent to which network interface card.
- if you want to use a ready-made solution, you can use Veins as the mobility source of a simulation that uses the INET Framework for modeling network traffic. (See the example of the Veins_INET subproject of Veins for sample code of how to do that.)

Comment: For the first approach, can I just add a new mac instance like the code snippet in BaseWaveAppLayer below?
(https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/d79fa2e166a69c9495adf1c1fc621168d7e4b66f/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L55)

Comment: The snippet you quoted does not instantiate a module. You might find the second approach to be much easier.